# Unir varias tablas en MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, codificación

Solicito ayuda ya que tengo un DB con 2 tablas, una llamada juegos y otra llamada clientes, lo que me cuesta es que mis clientes tienen varios juegos "comprados", pero no se como hacer la union ya sea con un JOIN o creando otra tabla en la que me muestre el cliente y me muestre el nombre de los juegos que tiene.
Adjunto estas 2 imagenes para ayuda (la llave foranea es para que me muestre solo el juego mas frecuente).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ingresa el código que has intentado

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: `select * from cliente join juegos on cliente.juego_frecuente = juegos.id;`